# JMeter Report Dashboard

Tags: csv, jmeter, report, jmeter-plugins

Most recent version of JMeter has an option to generate [Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which is great, but i am struggling to customize it to match my needs.

I am running performance tests for every new version of Application.

Lets start from current state of my reports.
I have User-Defined Variable named - Version. I am changing this for every new run of performance test.
Also, there is time stamp as a second type of comparison. - It is possible to compare previous results of the same version. Basically results from yesterday compare to today's results.

I am using [Flexible File Writer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) to save results to csv file. Using this plugin, it is perfectly easy to store version number(User-Defined variable) in every row, which is important for next step.

Results are imported to Excel Pivot table from where you can do basically everything.

Now, this above is ok, but it would be great to have created consolidated report directly from JMeter but there are few problems here. 
Report Dashboard is created from JMeter log file and here comes problems:

1. How to pass User-Defined Variable to log file?
2. How to make JMeter to continue with adding results to log file? 
   Currently it is asking to write new filename, so one test-one log file and i need: few tests-one log file.
3. How to Modify Jmeter properties to be able to compare results of more versions/more dates using JMeter [JMeter Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)? thnx

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JMeter Plugins Merge results.

Add a prefix with the date to the merge results.

For example :

LOGIN for date 1 will be date1:LOGIN or 2017_01_16:LOGIN

LOGIN for date 2 will be date2:LOGIN or 2017_01_17:LOGIN

https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/